# Can I use MySQL queries to create nested data structures with nested arrays and objects, or do I need to use JS?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am trying to construct an API for a front end service which expects a particular data structure when it requests an endpoint, `/questions`. My goal is to try and create a query that is able to access the data from all three tables and create a nested data structure that mimics the format that the front end expects. Is it possible to do this in a single query? Or is it better to just make a couple of individual queries and then use Javascript to format the data before sending it to the client?

I am using MySQL and have three tables, with the structure as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE Questions (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  product_id INT NOT NULL,
  body VARCHAR (255),
  date_written BIGINT,
  asker_name VARCHAR (55),
  asker_email VARCHAR (55),
  reported INT,
  helpful INT
);

CREATE TABLE Answers (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  question_id INT NOT NULL,
  body VARCHAR (255),
  date_written BIGINT,
  answerer_name VARCHAR (25),
  answerer_email VARCHAR (55),
  reported INT,
  helpful INT,

  FOREIGN KEY (question_id) REFERENCES Questions(id)
);

CREATE TABLE Answers_Photos (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  answer_id INT NOT NULL,
  url VARCHAR (255),

  FOREIGN KEY (answer_id) REFERENCES Answers(id)
);
```

The structure I need to return the data with is as follows:

```
{
  "pid": "47600",
  "results": [
      {
          "qid": 398619,
          "qbody": "Ut enim optio dolores",
          "qdate": "2021-02-11T00:00:00.000Z",
          "aname": "Mariana89",
          "qhelp": 23,
          "rep": false,
          "as": {
              "3731557": {
                  "id": 3731557,
                  "body": "Deserunt distinctio quam",
                  "date": "2021-08-06T00:00:00.000Z",
                  "aname": "Jack",
                  "help": 2,
                  "photos": []
              },
              "3731558": {
                  "id": 3731558,
                  "body": "Hic quam quos impedit quam perspiciatis labore facilis.",
                  "date": "2021-08-03T00:00:00.000Z",
                  "aname": "Evert14",
                  "help": 3,
                  "photos": []
              }
          }
      },
      {
          "qid": 398615,
          "qbody": "Deserunt nisi placeat officia doloribus.",
          "qdate": "2020-10-05T00:00:00.000Z",
          "aname": "Ember",
          "qhelp": 22,
          "rep": false,
          "as": {
              "3731506": {
                  "id": 3731506,
                  "body": "Sed ullam qui.",
                  "date": "2021-02-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                  "aname": "Doris12",
                  "help": 13,
                  "photos": [
                      "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1535639818669-c059d2f038e6?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=668&q=80"
                  ]
              },
              "3731507": {
                  "id": 3731507,
                  "body": "Fuga aute ducimus mollitia quaerat numquam ad.",
                  "date": "2021-02-19T00:00:00.000Z",
                  "aname": "Telly27",
                  "help": 4,
                  "photos": []
              },
              "3731508": {
                  "id": 3731508,
                  "body": "Debitis dicta quod aut incidunt.",
                  "date": "2020-12-17T00:00:00.000Z",
                  "aname": "Herman_Rogahn",
                  "help": 18,
                  "photos": [
                      "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1560095633-6803ba0461cd?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2734&q=80"
                  ]
              }
          }
      }
  ]
}
```

Comment: there are json function for that but if you can js do it there

Comment: Please tag appropriately.  MySQL <> SQL Server.  I removed the SQL Server tag.